# Sort NSArray of NSDictionary objects using NSSortDescriptor

Tags: ios, objective-c, sorting, nsdictionary, nssortdescriptor

I have an array of dictionaries that contain information about high scores. I am trying to figure out how to sort them by the different values in the dictionaries but cannot get it to work.

An example shown below attempts to sort by "Score":

```
NSDictionary *highScoreDictionary1 = @{@"Score" : @52, @"Duration" : @230 , @"Date" : [NSDate date]};
NSDictionary *highScoreDictionary2 =  @{@"Score" : @23, @"Duration" : @230 , @"Date" : [NSDate date]};
NSDictionary *highScoreDictionary3 = @{@"Score" : @35, @"Duration" : @230 , @"Date" : [NSDate date]};

NSArray *highScoresArray = @[highScoreDictionary1, highScoreDictionary2, highScoreDictionary3];

NSSortDescriptor *highScoreSortDescriptor = [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"Score" ascending:YES];  // Sort by Score
NSArray *sortDescriptorArray = [NSArray arrayWithObject:highScoreSortDescriptor];

[highScoresArray sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:sortDescriptorArray];
```

The output I get from `NSLog(@"sorted array of dictionaries: %@", highScoresArray);` is:

```
sorted array of dictionaries: (
        {
        Date = "2014-09-01 19:38:00 +0000";
        Duration = 230;
        Score = 52;
    },
        {
        Date = "2014-09-01 19:38:00 +0000";
        Duration = 230;
        Score = 23;
    },
        {
        Date = "2014-09-01 19:38:00 +0000";
        Duration = 230;
        Score = 35;
    }
)
```

How do I remedy this? Am I missing something here because it seems that the dictionaries are not being sorted by score.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
highScoresArray = [highScoresArray sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:sortDescriptorArray];
```

Comment: Ok wow...like I said I missed the most obvious explanation. I did not realize I was trying to change an immutable array / did not see the return variable was an NSArray *. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to sort an NSArray, which is immutable. You need to use the sort function to create a mutable array, i.e.

replace your:

```
[highScoresArray sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:sortDescriptorArray];
```

with:

```
NSMutableArray *newArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:[highScoresArray sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:@[highScoreSortDescriptor]]];
```

I have tested this and it seems to work.

Comment: Mutability is redundant here.

Comment: ok.. i'm pretty new to programming, but it still works and he gets an array that is sorted how he wants it :)

Comment: I never said it doesn't work, but there's room for improvement. :) Replacing `NSMutableArray` with `NSArray` makes this a legit answer, but your headline about the need of mutability is not reflected in the code.

Comment: or if you want to show the usage of NSMutableArray use `sortUsingComparator:` for in-place sorting.

Comment: @vikingosegundo and this is where Apple deceives devs into thinking that an in-place method always exist in the mutable counterpart class.

Comment: @keeshux, well, what does make you think it is not in-place?

Comment: Err no. I meant Apple didn't define a `[NSMutableArray sortUsingDescriptors:]` .. only to find it actually exists. Why `sortUsingComparator:` then?

Comment: oh, mistyping. I actually prefer comparators. the hand-based memory.

Comment: @GordonWorswick here's your mutable solution "fixed" for completeness: `NSMutableArray *newArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:highScoresArray]; [newArray sortUsingDescriptors:@[highScoreSortDescriptor]]; highScoresArray = newArray;`

Comment: or `NSMutableArray *newArray = [highScoresArray mutableCopy];` instead of `NSMutableArray *newArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:highScoresArray];`

Comment: Excellent thanks, it clicked as soon as you pointed it out the first time :)

Answer (score -1):

Try this approach

```
NSArray *sortedArray;
sortedArray = [highScoresArray sortedArrayUsingComparator:^NSComparisonResult(id a, id b) {
    NSDictionary *first = (NSDictionary*)a;
    NSDictionary *second = (NSDictionary*)b;

    int firstScore = [first objectForKey:@"score"];
    int secondScore = [second objectForKey:@"score"];

    if(firstScore > secondScore)
    {
        return NSOrderedDescending;
    }
    else if (firstScore < secondScore)
    {
        return NSOrderedAscending;
    }

    return NSOrderedSame;
}];
```

Got the code from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/805547/how-to-sort-an-nsmutablearray-with-custom-objects-in-it)

Comment: actually you must have copied a failing code: the comparator must return a NSComparisonResult value, not bool.

Comment: and also instead KVC's `valueForKey:` it should be NSDictionary's `objectForKey:` method. or just `first[@"score"]`

Comment: You're right. Sorry, didn't pay enough attention modifiying the code.